# Different API hit result with AsyncTask and PostMan

Tags: android, node.js, android-asynctask, kotlin, postman

I have a problem when I hit the backend API, I found a difference result on `Postman` and `AsyncTask` (httpPost). Why does it happen?

I use the `multer-s3-transform` nodejs plugin to upload the files into my backend API's, then stored on digitalocean spaces.

Below is a result from `AsyncTask`:

```
{
    "fieldname":"user_photo",
    "originalname":"IMG-20180308_0938_55321.jpg",
    "encoding":"7bit",
    "mimetype":"application/octet-stream",
    "size":84289,
    "bucket":"mycdn",
    "key":"1e9440387181846f54bece8a5d95a8a9",
    "acl":"public-read",
    "contentType":"image/jpeg",
    "metadata":null,
    "location":"https://mycdn.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/1e9440387181846f54bece8a5d95a8a9",
    "etag":"\"91ff71e41380602dbc35c94100f88d80\""
}
```

And this is one from `PostMan`:

```
{
    "fieldname": "user_photo",
    "originalname": "my-photos.png",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/png",
    "transforms": [
        {
            "id": "or",
            "size": 109955,
            "bucket": "mycdn",
            "key": "users/1520907984802.png",
            "acl": "public-read",
            "contentType": "image/png",
            "metadata": null,
            "location": "https://mycdn.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/users/1520907984802.png",
            "etag": "\"8e161cab4c516b5eb48c3c1c66987de9\""
        }
    ]
}
```

My final question, why is the `transforms` array not showing up in my `AsyncTask` result?

Comment: I think that it is negligible because all the content is also accessible with your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: From what I can tell, you are uploading a different file type (jpg vs png). Can you reproduce the differences when uploading the same file?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot why did it happen?

Comment: @PaulGeorgPodlech i thing its not about filename / file mimetype. i previously upload any images without `multer-s3-transform` and runs fine

Comment: @Bony Well, the file type is still an obvious difference in this response. It would be worth checking if it has any influence. The second thing you could try is to sniff the actual request sent by your implementation and compare it to the one in Postman.

Comment: @PaulGeorgPodlech thanks, im already done. it just change `builder.addPart()` to `builder.addBinaryBody()` and set the mimetype from original file before upload. :)